# Subtypes (inner entities) in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, entity, oracle-sql-data-modeler

How to create subtypes in logical model using user interface in Oracle SQL Data Modeler? I have one entity which is "VEHICLE" with atributes such as: date of production etc, and I'd like to add two subtypes: "CAR" and "MOTORCYCLE". I'd like to create imitation of inheritance.

I saw many logical models with such subtypes created in SQL data modeler, but I don't know how to create this. Subtypes should look like two inner entities nested inside "VEHICLE" class with attributes that are different than basic attributes of VEHICLE.

Comment: [CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375). Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an entity in Datamodeler one of the attributes is "Super type". When you add the CAR entity you can specify VEHICLE as it's supertype.

The CAR entity rectangle is then placed inside the VEHICLE rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The box in box representation of super type sub type is difficult to manage visually so you can change that by right clicking in diagram white space select Notation then uncheck "Box-in-Box Presentation"